# Filtering data by row Google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

I have a google sheet populated from a google form.
It gives the possibility in the form to enter multiple names in the same entry but I'd like to filter in a tab keeping all data but having a name per row in the sheet.
For example: >
[image: Response sheet]

I would like a formula that filters the data as follows:
[image]

Here is a test sheet showing the details: [Test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JXc-uMdzHHV9KE6IwBsE9yQQ4-KsYeVfG7psekZWW3Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Anyone could help with a formula like this?

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ,tocol(,1), reduce(Σ,'Form responses 1'!C2:index('Form responses 1'!P:P,match(,0/('Form responses 1'!A:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,vstack(if(iserror(a&""),Σ,a),
        if(len(c)*(not(isbetween(column(c),4,7))),hstack(index('Form responses 1'!A:B,row(c)),c,index('Form responses 1'!D:F,row(c))),Σ)))))
```

[image]